# How to load interstitial ads when Navigation Back Button Pressed and Some Click Event?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, interstitial

I am new to iOS development. I am adding an interstitial ads when `ViewDidLoad` but I want to show interstitial ads when an user clicks ten times in my application, is that possible? If it is possible then please help me finding a solution. My Application contains `HMSegmentedControll` and it has ten different  `UITableView`. And I also want to display these ads when `NavigationBar` back button is pressed. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

It is Possible like as SharedPreference in Android

Make One Global Variable NSObject like as

`GlobalVariable.h` File

```
@property (assign) int touchCount;
+ (TouchCount *)getInstance;
@end
```

and `GlobalVariable.m` File

```
@synthesize touchCount;
static TouchCount *instance = nil;

+(TouchCount *)getInstance
{
@synchronized(self)
{
    if(instance==nil)
    {
        instance= [TouchCount new];
    }
    if (instance.touchCount ==10)
    {
        instance.touchCount=0;
        instance= [TouchCount new];
    }
}
return instance;
}
```

And Use this Instance when You Want to Touch Count import `GLobalVariable.h`like as

```
TouchCount *obj=[TouchCount getInstance];
```

Answer (score 0):

Whell u can add some global value than counts "back taps"

in GlobalVariables.h file something like this:

```
 extern int PRJ_back_touches_count;
```

.m:

```
 int PRJ_back_touches_count;
```

Than e.g. in viewWillDisappear method PRJ_back_touches_count++

On viewDidAppear u can handle the PRJ_back_touches_count actual value